# Sonarqube git ci push reject

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-push

I know integrating git repo with sonarqube for code review by Git-CI.  Is that possible to reject the push, if sonarqube finds any error, codesmell, duplication from the sonar reivew results?